# How to search in listview populated on database?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I filled my **listview** on db. I want to search inside **listview**.
I want to search **name, surname and company** field after list on my listview.
This code returns **NullPointerException**.

myhomeclass:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.asrehber);

    dbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();

    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getAllPerson();
    String[] from = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_NAME,
            DBAdapter.KEY_SURNAME, DBAdapter.KEY_COMPANY };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.btnUserNameListItem,
            R.id.btnUserSurnameNameListItem };

    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.asrehber_single_list_item, cursor, from, to);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    dbHelper.close();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Intent viewCon = new Intent(ASRehber.this, PersonProfile.class);
            viewCon.putExtra(ROW_ID, id);
            startActivity(viewCon);
            finish();
        }
    });



    // Custom Search/////////////

    edtxtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtxtSearch);
    edtxtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
             ASRehber.this.dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}
```

mydataadapter:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_SURNAME = "surname";
public static final String KEY_COMPANY = "company";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ASRehber";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Person";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
        KEY_SURNAME, KEY_COMPANY, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_PHONE };

private final Context mCtx;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists "
        + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
        + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," + KEY_NAME + ","
        + KEY_SURNAME + "," + KEY_COMPANY + "," + KEY_EMAIL + ","
        + KEY_PHONE + ");";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    if (mDbHelper != null) {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }
}

public Cursor getAllPerson() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getPerson(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c = mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public long insertPerson(String name, String surname, String company,
        String email, String phone) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_SURNAME, surname);
    initialValues.put(KEY_COMPANY, company);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);

    return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

public boolean deletePerson(long rowId) {

    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return mDb.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}



public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String name, String surname,
        String company, String email, String phone) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    newValues.put(KEY_SURNAME, surname);
    newValues.put(KEY_COMPANY, company);
    newValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
    newValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
    // Insert it into the database.
    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}

}
```

Comment: what is the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Well it's quite simple. There is a chance that `dbHelper.getAllPerson();` will return null if it doesn't find any matching data. You just need to handle it.

Comment: im new on android. where ad this handle.

Comment: Could you tell where exactly you get the NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't close the database until your don't need any of it's cursors anymore. SimpleCursorAdapter (and almost anything that uses Cursors in general) does not keep all data in memory, instead it will query it's cursor for new rows when they are needed (e.g. when user scrolls the list or when you attempt to filter the list). Instead close database in `onDestory()` method of Activity, using it.

2) When you close something (cursor, database, stream - anything) do it in `finally {}` block.

3) You really should consider using storing data in ContentProvider and using Loaders to access it - this approach makes database access much simpler and avoids stalling main thread by long SQL queries.

Comment: ok. thanks for your suggestion. but i cannot solve my problem this tip.